# Access a controller function when inside a loop (ChildrenOf)

Tags: silverstripe

I have a page type (`ProducerReport`) which acts like a summary page - it gets data from individual pages (`Shows`) and lists them all on one page with the main info from each article.

Using `ChildrenOf()` made it really easy and simple, I thought wow SilverStripe will do all the work for me all I have to do is structure and style it!

But then tragedy struck...

In `Shows` I have a DataObject linked by $has_many which allows users to add key people such as contacts etc for each individual article, this is done via GridField (`ShowsContacts`).

At first I kind of assumed that simply adding the necessary variables would get the data from `ShowContacts` - this didn't work.

Then in the view I took a shot in the dark and tried using `$ID` which actually worked and returned the ID of the post.

So I went ahead I added this into the `ProducerReport` controller which I hoped would get the job done, allowing me to perform a query to get the relevant contacts and loop it within in the `ChildrenOf` loop.

However, the controller doesn't do anything while in the loop. The only time it outputs anything is when I put the outside of the loop.

**ProducerReport.php**

```
class ProducerReport_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    # Get the Show Contacts for the Show, based on ShowsID
    public function something($SiteID){

        # Needs to be cast to int as param comes in as string
        $x = (int)$SiteID;
        var_dump(ShowsContact::get()->find('ShowID', $x)->Role);

    }
}
```

**ProducerReport.ss**

```
<div class="producer-report">

<% loop ChildrenOf(current-shows).sort('PercentageComplete', 'DESC') %>

    <div class="show">

        <div class="banner">
        <% if $ReportImage %>
            $ReportImage
        <% else %>
            <img src="/assets/_placeholders/producer_report_cover.png" />
        <% end_if %>

            <a href="$Link" title="View $Title Show Page"><h2>$Title <span>($ProjectCode)</span></h2></a>

        </div><!-- . banner -->

        <a class="hub-link" target="_blank" href="http://website.com?job=$ProjectCode">Hub</a><!-- . hub-link -->

        <div class="stats">

            <h3>Show Statistics</h3>

            <dl>
                <dt>Client</dt>
                <% if $Client %>
                    <dd>$Client</dd>
                <% else %>
                    <dd>None set</dd>
                <% end_if %>
            </dl>

            <dl>
                <dt>Percentage Complete</dt>
                <% if $PercentageComplete %>
                    <dd>$PercentageComplete%</dd>
                <% else %>
                    <dd>-</dd>
                <% end_if %>

            </dl>

        </div><!-- . stats -->

    </div><!-- . show -->

    <!-- Here I need to retrieve info of the contacts belonging to the page -->

    <!-- Inside the ChildrenOf loop, this DOESNT output anything -->
    $something($ID)

<% end_loop %>

    <!-- This outside the loop DOES output a job role -->
    $something(84)

</div><!-- . producer report -->
```

### EDIT - Additional code

This here is what the `ProducerReport` gets data from, all direct data for this Model appears in that `ChildrenOf` loop; The `ShowsContact` data isn't accessible and if I try to query using the `$something($ID)` functionality it doesn't work when used inside the loop.

**Shows.php**

```
class Shows extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        'ProjectCode' => 'Varchar(4)',
        'Client' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'PercentageComplete' => 'Int'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'ReportImage' => 'Image'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'ShowsContacts' => 'ShowsContact'
    );

    public function getCMSFields(){

        # GridField / Show Contacts
        $conf = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();

        $gridField = new GridField('ShowsContact',
                                   'Show Contact List',
                                   $this->ShowsContacts(), $conf);

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Content.ShowContact', array(
            $gridField
        ));

        return $fields;

    }
}

class Shows_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    # Get key people from ShowsContact class // input via ShowsContact GridField

    # THIS HERE is the data that I need displayed on ProducerReport

    public function getKeyPeople(){

        if($this->ShowsContacts()->exists()){

            $result = new ArrayList();

            foreach($this->ShowsContacts()->column('MemberID') as $teamMemberID){

                $member = Member::get()->byID($teamMemberID);

                $result->add(new ArrayData(array(
                    'PictureURL' => $member->ImageURL,
                    'Role' => $this->ShowsContacts()->find('MemberID', $teamMemberID)->Role,
                    'Firstname' => $member->FirstName,
                    'Surname' => $member->Surname,
                    'Nickname' => $member->Nickname,
                    'Email' => $member->Email,
                    'Ext' => $member->Extension,
                    'Site' => Site::get()->byID($member->SiteID)->Title
                    )
                ));
            }

            return $result;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

---

My question is - how would I get data from another page type as well as data that's linked to it by relationship if I am unable to do a loop within a loop - or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So where I am using `ShowContact` in the controller as that is the name of the DataObject that I'm trying query, I attempted to make it `ShowContacts` and now get this error message `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ShowsContacts' not found` -- is this because `ProducerReport` needs it to **find** the data or because I'm making SilverStripe think I want to establish a relationship from that page type to `ShowContact`??

Comment: I'm a little confused by the `ChildrenOf` stuff you mentioned at the top and your relationship between the DataObjects, can you show more of your code relating to these parts/what you tried?

Comment: @Turnerj Added in some more info, hope that helps clear things up. Do let me know if you have any other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>AHHHH!! omfg!!!!</strike> Okay, so after taking many *many* shots at this issue I found out how to get this working.

The solution to this is to use $Top.[Method] inside the loop. I assume its because SilverStripe is doing it's own thing within the loop and for whatever reason becomes a bit blind. From what I understand - you have to tell the method to go outside the loop in order for it to see / use the Controller

Going from the code above in `ProducerReport.ss` and trimming it down for relevance to the question...

```
<% loop ChildrenOf(current-shows).sort('PercentageComplete', 'DESC') %>
...
    $Top.something($ID) <!-- works perfectly, ID is passed. Output is as expected!
...

# Or when in a loop it'll be like so...

    <% loop $Top.something($ID) %>
        # ArrayList / ArrayData output...
    <% end_loop %>

<% end_loop %>
```

---

I can't believe this took me so long to find a solution!
May anyone who gets stuck on something like this or anything similar find their way to this answer because I was honestly about to give up and rewrite everything for this page type and use queries to get all the data to put in the template...

---

***Edit / Note***: I've found that if you have a method called `getUserName` (for example) you cannot omit the 'get' when using it with `$Top` ... so in the template you need to put `$Top.getUserName` when using it

Comment: Ahhhh, now I know what you're talking about. Yeah, that is what you were looking for. It is referred to as Template Scope and the [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4.0/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#scope) goes into detail about. Short answer is that it is intentionally built this way and it can be quite powerful. :)

Comment: Cheers dude, that's actually where I got the idea to try using `$Top` but the documentation never really goes that in-depth into the use cases for it, I only tried it because I was all out of ideas and it just so happened to be what I needed! I've used `$Top` before but never thought it'd be needed for something like this. Thanks for checking in though, it's much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's relevant if you think you've fixed your problem, but the `something` controller method (is that even used?) will never dump what you think it will as any `DataObject::get()` or `DataList::create()` ORM calls always return an instance of `DataList`, not an individual `DataObject`.

If you're trying to see what SS has from that query, try using `->first()` instead, which as you might guess, returns the first `DataObject` (or `DataObject` subclass) in your list:

```
...
var_dump(ShowsContact::get()->find('ShowID', $x)->first()->Role);
```

Comment: I think I understand where you're coming from because I have seen var_dump outputting things I didn't expect. Although I don't think its the case in this situation. What I have in my answer returns the `Roles`. Trying the above gave me a server error (maybe as I'm on 3.2?) and using `var_dump(ShowsContact::get()->find('ShowID', (int)$SiteID)->first->Role);` gave me a list of NULL lol - And no, `something` isn't going to be used it was just a quickly and easily named method for testing while I figured out how to get data inside a loop :)

Comment: "first" is a method not a property/field and you can lose the `(int)` typecast too:

`var_dump(ShowsContact::get()->find('ShowID', $SiteID)->first()->Role);`

Answer (score -1):

For your template you could do this:

ProducerReport.ss

```
<% loop Shows %>
    <% loop ShowsContacts %>
        <%-- contact details here --%>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Where 'ShowsContacts ' is the name of the relation from shows to contacts

Comment: Nope, sorry but that didn't do anything. Attempted inside and outside the loop with no results